# Which version of OpenGL ES in New Boston Tutorials?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm going to start learning to use OpenGL ES for Android now, and there are some tutorials from The New Boston on YouTube, but I'm not sure if he's using version 1 or 2 of OpenGL ES? I guess it's no good idea to learn about version 1 nowdays!? How can I see what version that is used?

He's using a method called `onSurfaceCreated` and the type for the parameter is GL10. Does thist means he's using version 1 of Open GL ES?

Preciate the help to clarify this before I continue! I also apreciate tips of good tutorials of openGL ES for Android! Thansk! :)

Linkt to one of the tutorials: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_asBr_txZU

Comment: `He's using a method called onSurfaceCreated and the type for the parameter is GL10. Does thist means he's using version 1 of Open GL ES?` no ... it depends on settings (fx in `GLSurfaceView` constructor use `setEGLContextClientVersion`) ... then for GL10 you can use GL context from method(`gl` param) ... for GLES20 you can use static bindings (methods from android.opengl.GLES20 class)without GL context ... samples ... well ... you can find them fx.: in $adsdk\samples\android-10\BasicGLSurfaceView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching the tutorial N. 174, I can say that these tutorials series are definitely for OpenGLES 1 : if there is no Vertex and Fragment shaders, there is no OpenGLES 2, besides in Android, OpenGLES 2 methods always begins with GLES20. I recommand [Google tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html) to start with OpenGLES 2 for Android, and this [book](http://opengles-book.com/) is just amazing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Since I wrote my question here I found some information that it's easier to learn verson 1 of OpenGL ES, and that's perhaps enough if I'm going to create a simple game!? The book feels a little bit old!? 2008!

Comment: Well using opengles 1 or 2 depends on your needs, in fact for a simple game GLES1 is good enough ;), and the book is Old because GLES2 is old too :D (it was released in 2007).